# XmlWriter Run Time Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, vb.net, soap

When I use XmlWriter to write XML file, I've encountered a following problem:

what I need to write :

```
<soap:Body>some xml</soap:Body>
```

I've tried to use **XmlWriter.WriteStartElement method**

```
 XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("soap:Body")
```

, but I'll get a runtime exception like "I**nvalid name character in 'soap:Body'. The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A,** cannot be included in a name."

I am new to xmlwriter,I dont know about overloaded with namespace

if u konow about it Suggest way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first have to declare that namespace (`soap`), then you can use it with `WriteStartElement`.

Example:

```
writer.WriteStartElement("root");

// Declare a namespace with AttributeString
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "soap", null, "something:something");

// Use it here
writer.WriteStartElement("Body", "something:something");

writer.WriteString("some xml");
writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.WriteEndElement();
```

The result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns:soap="something:something">
  <soap:Body>some xml</soap:Body>
</root>
```

---

If you want to use a prefix in the root element, you can use something like this:

```
var soap = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope";

// use prefix with namespace
writer.WriteStartElement("soap", "Envelope", soap);
writer.WriteStartElement("Body", soap);
writer.WriteString("some xml");
writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.WriteEndElement();
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap:Body>some xml</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```